# How to redirect the url of old modified directories

Tags: php, rewrite

I have a website for classifieds ads. Before I used to modify the `URL`s to make them more appropriate, but the old `URL`s are still showing up in Google index and in browser history/bookmarks.

Is there any way to by pass or redirect the old `URL`s to the new ones? I tried using `.htaccess` rules but cant get the the result I want.

For example:

1. [Before modification](http://example.com/vehicles-cars/other-vehicles/selling-my-2010-toyota-sequioa-19500-9585.htm)
2. [After modification](http://example.com/vehicles-cars-for-sale/other-vehicles/selling-my-2010-toyota-sequioa-19500-9585.htm)

As it happens at the moment, both of the URLs work, which is bad for Search Engine Optimization (SEO). I need the first `URL` to redirect to the second `URL`.

This is exactly what is in my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
ErrorDocument 404 /content/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^vehicles-cars/?(.*),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

What webserver are you running? Edit that in your question please.

Assuming it's Apache and you have mod_rewrite on, append the following line in your .htaccess file found at the root directory of your host.

```
RewriteRule ^vehicles-cars/?(.*) http://adsbuz.com/vehicles-cars-for-sale/$1
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: thanks Panagiotis M for your quick response this trick i already used in my .htaccess file but not working this is what exactally is in my .htaccess file actually the problem

Comment: thanks Panagiotis M for your quick response this trick i already used in my .htaccess file but not working  i am adding details in main post thanks again for prompt reply

Comment: The snippet I gave as an aswer should do be working, any match to vehicles-cars is redirected to the correct/new url type.
Now regarding the 'middle' parameters of the url as you stated in your edited post, I am guessing that the script you are using just examines the accessed url and sends out content as a match from the last integer number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a 301 redirect from the old URL. Given that *both* of those URLs currently work, I wouldn't touch your rewrite rules, as I think that will be more complicated than it needs to be, because you will need to know which one is the current URL and which one is the old URL *at rewrite level*, which it looks like your app is not designed for.

What I would do instead, is when the PHP starts executing, the first thing it needs to do is check the current URL of the request (`content-location`). Compare what's in that string to what's in your database for the page.

If the two URLs match, then load the page normally. Otherwise, do a [301 Header Redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to the new URL.

Answer (score -2):

see this: [301 and 302 redirects using mod rewrite tutorial](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/basic-tutorials-lesson-2.php)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.